# Woocommerce: programmaticaly set the shipping class

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to set a free shipping to some specific products of the cart in Woocommerce. I am using this code setting the shipping class at 0 on condition:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_shipping_costs', 50, 1 );
function change_shipping_costs( $cart ) { 
    if ( ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) )
        return;
    
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){        
        if ( ...some conditions... ) {            
              $cart_item['data']->set_shipping_class_id('0');
        }
    }
}
```

This works for simple products (shipping cost not added) but for a reason I don’t understand it is not working with variable products (the shipping cost is still added). Is there someone who had a similar problem?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally make it work. the problem was that for variable products, when a variation has no shipping class (or not existing class) Woocommerce takes the one defined in the generic "shipping" class tab (so, instead of the shipping class defined in the "variations" tab). That was my problem as I was setting the class id to '0' which is a not existing class.

The solution was to create a new shipping class (zero) and set its cost to 0. Then use this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_shipping_costs', 50, 1 );
function change_shipping_costs( $cart ) {
    
    if ( ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) )
        return;

    //Loop the cart items 
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        
        if ( ...some conditions... ) {
            // The shipping class id must be set to the "zero" shipping class id 
            $cart_item['data']->set_shipping_class_id(get_the_shipping_class_id('zero'));   
        }
    }
}

// Get the shipping class id by slug
function get_the_shipping_class_id( $slug ) {
    $shipping_class_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $slug, 'product_shipping_class' );
    if ( $shipping_class_term ) {
        return $shipping_class_term->term_id;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Bye.